# how to display overlay on two frames?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I need to display overlay on two frames. I don't have any idea. I know only overlay within one frame.

```
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
<frame src="frame_a.htm">
<frame src="frame_b.htm">
<frame src="frame_c.htm">
</frameset>
```

I have one link in `frame_b.htm.` if I click that link overlay div or overlay JSP should display entire frameset.
How can we display overlay div on more than one frame?
can it possible?

please help me with HTML CSS and jsp(no jquery, no iframe)

Comment: It looks like you're using frames to lay out content. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: yes i am using frames to lay out content.

Comment: if this idea is wrong. please suggest me right thing.

Comment: Simply do it one page and include the separate parts. For example in php `include('menu.php');` will include that file. Look into **server side includes** to include HTML in HTML.